# Making a custom expression "portable"...?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

In a QGIS project im using a **custom expression**.

As far as i know they are stored **locally** in a .py file located in the user profile.

What would be the solution to make this custom expression "portable" so that my QGIS project could be distributed ?

Is there any possibilities to define this custom expression in the project's python macros ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can safely move the expression definition to sit within a particular project's startup macro and all will work as expected.